Rank the sensitivity among multiple calibration curves
Let's say that, with a measurement device, we have a linear relationship between an output measurement I (in mV) and the concentration C of an analyte. The goal is to measure C.
We have 3 different hardware configurations of the device which impact the sensitivity:

configuration 1 : I = a_1 * C + b_1

configuration 2 : I = a_2 * C + b_2

configuration 3 : I = a_3 * C + b_3


How to define, with a numeric indicator, the sensitivity of our configuration, in regard to the concentration C?
Intuitively, the higher the a_i value, the most sensitive is our device (which outputs I) in regard to small variations of C.
But on the other hand, among these two calibration curves:
I = 0.2 * C + 1000    std=100     (1)
I = 0.1 * C + 100     std=10      (2)

(2) is probably a calibration with higher sensitivity, even if the slope 0.1 is the lowest, because
0.1/10 > 0.2/1000, i.e. the noise is 10 times less.
This argument is rather hand-wavy, how to formalize this with a more rigourous numeric indicator?
Note: in What is $\frac{a}{b}$ called in a $y=a x+b$ regression in the context of a physical detection test? I thought about slope / intercept as indicator, but there are surely more general indicators.
Is the indicator slope / std common in chemometrics, does it have a name?

What does std refer to? Why do you involve the intercept?

@SextusEmpiricus It is just an example, std for standard deviation when you repeat, say, 100 measurements. About your 2nd part of the question: intercept does have meaning. Let's say you have 100 + 0.1 x    vs.  100000000000 + 0.2 x, look at what happens if you have 0.1% measurement acquisition errors. The 2nd calibration has a better slope but the results will be worse. This shows the intercept is important.

@Basj the error being relarive in % is not made explicit in this question. It the error is a constant level then the intercept plays no role. Could you update a clarification about this in the question.

I already assumed that std stands for standard deviation, but I don't know what it refers to in the context. Is it the noise level of a measurement? Where does it suddenly come from? In the introduction you specify 3 configurations without considering the noise level, then in the second part you suddenly make a comparison where you have this std without explaining what it relates to.

The IUPAC definition of sensitivity (in metrology and analytical chemistry) is

 The slope of the calibration curve. If the curve is in fact a 'curve', rather than a straight line, then of course sensitivity will be a function of analyte concentration or amount. If sensitivity is to be a unique performance characteristic, it must depend only on the chemical measurement process, not upon scale factors.

So, the sensitivities are indeed your $a_i$, noise does not enter sensitivity.
You may say things like:

calibration (1) has higher sensitivity but also higher noise.
Or even: calibration (1) achieves higher sensitivity, but at the cost of even higher noise.



Is the indicator slope / std common in chemometrics, does it have a name?

I've never met it as "standalone" figure of merit before. But note that its reciprocal appears prominently e.g. in the DIN 32645 way of calculating limits of detection and quantification, the fast approximations via blank measurement standard deviation, etc.
